# Clion и cmake:изменить (добавить) переменную окружения перед запуском приложения

Tags: c++, cmake, clion

Имеется [приложение](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/nathan-osman/785152e6452559852fc8/raw/ea10e57d2df555b3a31d5e6f976be89332ba388b/path.cpp), которое выводит содержимое переменной окружения:path.

В `clion`, при построении проекта и запуске экзешника по умолчанию он выводит, напр:`C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;` - ну и так далее.

Нужно прописать в cmake или в настройках, чтобы экзешник при запуске выводил еще один путь, добавленный к переменной path, напр:`c:\MY_FOLDER;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;`

И этот путь всегда добавлять динамически при запуске приложения и также запуске новых приложений, добавленных посредством `add_executable`.

Comment: Вы запускаете приложение другим способом, чем через `add_custom_command`. Зачем тогда смотреть [вопросы](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35029277/how-to-modify-environment-variables-passed-to-custom-cmake-target) про эту команду? Сам по себе CMake не ассоциирует дополнительные переменные окружения с создаваемым приложением. Но в любой "нормальной" IDE должен быть способ настроить переменные окружение при запуске программы из этой IDE. К сожалению, я практически не знаком с CLion. Возможно, кто-то более знающий сможет помочь.

Comment: Ну, `clion` и `cmake` очень тесно, связаны. Я предполагал, что одним из вариантов будет создание `add_custom_target`, так как уже перерыл все что можно.

Comment: На скриншоте в этом [вопросе](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33267305/how-to-setup-clion-for-compile-and-run) показано окно настройки запуска приложения в CLion. Поле "Environment" явно предназначено для ввода дополнительных переменных окружения. (Вопрос на английском, я "разучился" искать на русском :)

Comment: Да туда тоже лазил, но автоматизации  и там не добился. Получалось только лишь хардкодом прописывать path -"простыню" вместо того чтобы изящно добавить только один путь к имеющимся. Вот и тогда начал думать за `cmake`

Answer (score 1):

У нас есть задача в трекере CLion: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/CPP-15061.

Пожалуйста, проголосуйте за нее или добавьте комментарий.

В качестве обходного пути можно или задать переменную полностью средствами CLion, или изменить ее средствами CMake

```
set(ENV{PATH} "$ENV{PATH};<new path>")
```

Comment: Привет! Вы из JetBrains? Ваш комментарий ценный, но на полноценный ответ по правилам сайта не тянет, потому что решения нет. Есть ли сейчас какой-то обходной путь?

Comment: @Ann Filippova, спасибо, но если средствами CMake (как вы говорите в ответе), то переменная будет меняться только на этапе построения, и не повлияет на переменную `PATH` которую видит запускаемое приложение. (AFAIK :))